# Get data from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing this first time. I have created an `iframe` on my page and I want the text from the `iframe` through `jquery`.
Here is my code :

```
<html>
  <head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function copyIframeContent(iframe){  
        var iframeContent = $(iframe).contents(); //alert(iframeContent);
        //$("#result").text("Hello World");
        $("#result").html(iframeContent.find('body').html);alert(iframeContent.find('body').html());
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" onload="copyIframeContent(this);" name="myIframe" src="text.php"></iframe><br />
    Result:<br />
    <textarea id='result'></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="click" id="btn" onclick="aa()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function aa(){  alert("Fdf");
            alert(document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

text.php:

```
text to change
```

I tried a lot in all browsers but still this is not working.
Can anyone help me to get this content?

Comment: yes its a same page and in same directory

Comment: " but still not working" Im just wondering what that means? Please elaborate by giving us error message if any

Comment: i have copy/paste here my wholde code but still its now working dontknow why. in alert it shows me [ObectObject]

Comment: Don't use alert, use console.log() and check object

Comment: it shows me this error " Permission denied to access property 'document'" in console

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path for src iframe?

Comment: yes but same thing happend. no change in result

Comment: Be aware, if your root path is 'h-t-t-p://www.mysite.com/index.php', the absolute path for test.php must be 'h-t-t-p://www.mysite.com/test.php' and not 'h-t-t-p://mysite.com/test.php'   The opposite is true too  {i've to escape http in order to not render it as link}

Answer (score 4):

The contentWindow works in both FF and chrome

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document.body
```

Would give you a DOM element body

You can also try something like

```
 window.frames['myIframe'].document.body
```

That might do the trick for you also

You might have problems with your browsers built in security. If you run this on a local machine. There is a way to disable browsers security.

Comment: first i watn the text from the text from the iframe and then i want to replace it with my div(result)

Comment: (document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document.body).appendchild(div(result))                                                                   

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp

Answer (score 3):

Use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get to iFrame's DOM.

```
$('#myIframe').contents()
```

**UPDATE:**

In the OP:

```
$("#result").html(iframeContent.find('body').html);
```

Should say:

```
$("#result").html(iframeContent.find('body').html());
```

Comment: its now working.. i alert this and i get "[obect Object]" in the alert box

Comment: `$('#myIframe').contents().find('body').html()` too? .contents() alone returns jQuery.

Comment: "not working" is not enough description, I'm afraid. Have you tried to `console.log` this instead of `alert`? Then you'll be able to actually see inside the Object returned and see what's what. Btw. no security errors in the console?

Answer (score 3):

```
var content=$("iframe").contents().find('body').html();

alert(content);
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 1):

Doing with jquery will be a little easier:

```
$('Your Selector', frames['myIframe'].document)
```

The above example will get anything from *myIframe*. But the iframe MUST be from the same domain as the parent document. If not from the same domain, a security violation occurs (You can't add content from foreign sites to your page and change that content.)

If no security violation, you can do anything with the selection. For example  you can use the jquery append() method to insert new html inside the iFrame, you can use the html() method to replace html or any other function that jquery/pure javascript allows.