# open php in an iframe and extract the data to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, iframe

I have created a html app that is deployed from my domain (ex.www.sample.com/example.html.  mysql is also on same domain

I am opening a www.sample.com/data.php url within my iframe to display mySQL data.(this is the example data showing (1234)) what am trying to do is extract that data from within the iframe and place in a variable so i can extract it using javascript and use that data later.  the web app i believe only allows me to use html and javascript.

this is the code i am using

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="http://www.sample.com/data.php" name="iframe1" width="480px" height="400px" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

javascript to extract

```
<script>
function getdata(){
var check = document.getElementById("iframe1).contentWindow.a
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the data is output directly in the body of the iframe, you can do:

```
var iFrameBody = document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.document.body;
```

Possible duplicate: [Get data from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589306/get-data-from-iframe)

However, if you are using the iframe only to display data, this is not the best way to do it. I would recommend you creating a simple API that outputs JSON data and then fetch this data in your HTML app using AJAX.

Comment: i tried creating this script but receiving error cannot read property"contentwindow" of null.  here is the script  i tried to use  `<script>
function getdata(){
var iFrameBody = document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.document.body;
setvaluex("text1",iFrameBody)
}
</script>` setvaluex(text1) is the API within the program i use to set value to textbox

Comment: So no object is being found by the function getElementById. Try adding  an ```id="iframe1"``` attribute to your iframe tag.

Comment: And also: you will have to get the text content of the iframe's body depending on what your function setvaluex does. So the property ```iFrameBody.textContent``` may be useful.

Comment: ok this is what i am trying and getting nowhere. First thing first, current browsers will be chrome, safari, windows my html app does not work so well in explorer.   i tried modify code but no such luck, i am receiving cannot read textcontent   `var iFrameBody = document.getElementById("iframe1").iFrameBody.textContent;`

Comment: I got it to work but only in internet explorer using  `<script> function getdata(){ var iFrameBody = document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.document.body; setvaluex("text1",iFrameBody) } </script>` just need to understand how to get chrome, safari

Comment: This works across all google,explorer,safari tested.  Thanks .  If i wanted to to extract the 2nd line of the iframe how abouts would i go about doing that.

Comment: Please show (paste here a screenshot maybe) how the data is output in the source code of the iframe ```<body>```. I believe textContent should return all text inside the element as it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: not sure i understand, i can display the data single word on each line or stringed together on a contineous line.  What i am trying to do now is pick the 2nd word from the body of the iframe instead of all the contents

Comment: Search for the split() method in strings, that is what you want. If you do ```var a = str.split(" ");```, ```a``` will be an array which contains in each value a word from the string ```str```. Then you can get the 2nd word by doing ```a[1]```.

Comment: can you help me out i am stuck on trying to split all the data into different variable so if i have in my iframe the names: mike smith john smith tim smith how do i create a variable for each name including lastname, so there would be 3 variable

Comment: A simple way to do this (knowing that all names have exactly 2 names - one firstname and one lastname - is by simply concatenating the values of the array: ```var b = a[0] + a[1]``` and so on... There are many ways to do this and this is a very elementary question, so I think you should search for a JavaScript tutorial or something like that. A book I would definitely recomend is http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: Exactly right, that was exactly I was looking for..thanks