# Set Iframe Value From Field Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, onload-event

I have a CRM form with an iframe on it that contains an HTML textarea (id=textbox). On the form, I have a field called "Justification". I need the textarea value that is in the iframe, to be set to the value that is in the "Justification" field on the parent form Onload using javascript. is there a simple way to do this, and if so, can you provide a script? Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589306/get-data-from-iframe)

Comment: Does the iframe src have the same domain as the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few different way to accomplish that goal, since you state a onload event in your tags, you could go with:

```
var parentValue = parent.document.getElementById("Justification").value;
document.getElementById("textbox").value = parentValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe src and the parent exist on the same domain you can use the `contentWindow` of the iframe to access the DOM elements. [MDN contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

If they don't exist on the same domain then the browser will prevent you from manipulating the DOM due to cross-origin restrictions.

If you have access to the source code for the parent and the iframe you could implement `window.postMessage()` to pass data between the parent and iframe. [MDN postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)