# Is it possible to target a div from another html file using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML/JS front-end app connected to a back-end. This application is written by someone else and is stand alone with some continuously updated data. What I wish to do is write a web app that could retrieve some data from this app and display it in my app. Can I target a specific `div` in the other app in my app and use its content?

Comment: You can only select elements by id or class which a currently in the DOM. If your web app is rendered on the same page, then you could do that. But here is more information needed. What kind of backend is it? If it is an independent backend like a nodejs server, where you could retrieve the data in any web app you want and work with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589306/get-data-from-iframe)

Comment: Are you trying to scrape data?

Comment: @xDrago, no, the back-end is specific to that app only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

## 1. Send a GET request

You should send a GET request from your backend (sorry, you will need one) to the target source to get back the HTML.

## 2. Mine the div from the response

There are many ways to do so. If you use Javascript, then you could create an invisible `div`, where you would dump whatever is inside the `body` tag.

## 3. Query the div you are interested in

Now their `div` is in your structure. Query it as you like.

Comment: I don't have access to the server though. It's specific to that app.

Comment: @BlackMath let's clarify: there are two servers involved. The first server is the one where you are downloading the page from. The second server is the one you need to run and use as a proxy. Modern browsers are protecting against CORS, so you will not be able to solve this using client-side only. You will need a thin server.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. I was hoping to do that only from the front-end. My app is actually just a front-end :). Out of curiosity, how can I send a get request to the other server? How do I know the end point, for example? I am still learning this stuff, so excuse the question if it's silly.

Comment: @BlackMath don't worry, we've all been there at some point. Since you are already reasonably comfortable with Javascript, I recomment the use of NodeJS, as Javascript-base server. Here you can find an article about sending requests with NodeJS: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Comment: @BlackMath here you can read about setting up a simple NodeJS webserver: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to find out what is displaying the text in the div, and use your own API calls to replicate it. I unfortunately can't help you with this because you provided no information regarding the back-end. However, if you need to access the div's content, you can create a hidden iframe loading the necessary HTML, and access the DOM of the iframe.

```js
async function getContentFromHTML(html, id) {
  let frame = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.body.appendChild(frame);
  frame.style.display = 'none';
  frame.src = html;
  let content = await new Promise(function(resolve, _reject) {
    frame.contentWindow.onload = () => resolve(frame.contentDocument.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
  });
  return content;
}
```

Note that this may allow the other HTML page to access the window of your page, and the HTML page you are trying to load may not be accessible from an iframe, but I won't go into XSS trust here.