# difficulty getting data from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

There's an extension which I need to extract data from, and currently the relevant data is copied by hand to a spreadsheet, whereas it'd be faster to copy the data to clipboard and paste as tab-delimited data directly into the spreadsheet.

However, the popup's classes can't seem to be found using getElementByClassName, nor can they be found by id.

This seems to be because they are in an iframe. From elsewhere on SO, I've tried getting the iframe object, and getting the `.document attribute`, `.contentWindow.document`, but neither have worked. I was thinking it might be because there is a #document in the html immediately following the iframe before the html starts?

The relevant HTML code looks like:

```
<iframe ...>
  #document
     <html ...>
<\iframe>
```

Many thanks for you help

Comment: Is that iframe content loaded from the same domain as the parent document? If not, then you have no JavaScript access to the iframe's innards at all, keyword _Same Origin Policy_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589306/get-data-from-iframe)

Comment: The 'src' attribute for the iframe is from a different domain @CBroe

Comment: so it can be the case that I can see the html of the popup in my browser's inspect, but not access it with javascript?

Comment: Yes, exactly. What _you_ see in the dev tools, doesn't harm anyone. But JavaScript code running in the parent page might not be _your_ code to begin with, you could be on a site you don't even own. No if that iframe was to show any of your personal data, and a script that wasn't even yours could access (and therefor _steal_) that data, that would be bad.

Comment: @CanO'Spam I've already looked there, and while `window.frames['sasFrame']` returns the frame, it lacks any document value, i.e., `window.frames['sasFrame'].document` does nothing

Comment: ah perfect thank you @CBroe is that what is being referenced by the error message: `Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.`
in the console?

Comment: No, that does not appear to be related. https://github.community/t/i-have-no-idea-what-the-interest-cohort-is/179780